# Ti.Modules Always not found in alloy titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I had doing for using Map Module, as explained from docs : http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map

but when I debug my application, the error always appear like this :

```
[error] dalvikvm: Could not find class 'ti.modules.titanium.map.TiMapActivity', referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.map.ViewProxy.createView
```

Ti.map Modules always not found.

I am also doing like this ref : http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

and trying as answered at this trhead : https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121105/crash-in-android-when-using-maps

and also do like this too : 
http://cbpbenitez.blogspot.com/2013/06/android-mapsv2-module-sample-code-in.html

but the errors always same. Ti.Map Modules always not found.

I am confused how to fix this problem.
can someone help me how to fix this  ?

thanks a millions.

Comment: Did you download the module and put it in your `modules` directory inside your project?